# How do I register a newly written WP-CLI command locally?

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

I've followed the [Commands Cookbook](http://wp-cli.org/docs/commands-cookbook/).

And I've written a function, and called `WP_CLI::add_command` but I don't see how to make that command available.

I tried

```
$ wp --debug eval-file getcsv.php update-recommended
```

and get this output:

```
Debug: No readable global config found (0.009s)
Debug: No project config found (0.01s)
Debug: Loading packages from: /root/.wp-cli/packages/vendor/autoload.php (0.012s)
Debug: ABSPATH defined: /home/studleys/public_html/mailorder/ (0.021s)
Debug: Running command: eval-file (0.021s)
Debug: Begin WordPress load (0.022s)
Debug: wp-config.php path: /home/studleys/public_html/mailorder/wp-config.php (0.022s)
Debug: Loaded WordPress (1.608s)
Success: The script is about to be registered!
```

The "Success:..." message is echoed using `WP_CLI::success()` just before the WP_CLI::add_command() call, but the registered command is NOT being run.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be simple [wp-cli.yml](http://wp-cli.org/config/).  The clue was:

```
Debug: No project config found (0.01s)
```

So I added one:

```
# cat wp-cli.yml
color: true
require:
  - getcsv.php
```